# construct2 volume adjust with angles

Tags: construct-2

new to construct and need some help getting a knob to set the volume of a track. How do i get the the know to stay within angles and adjust the volume to the attached audio accorindly. The image has the current angles i want to stay between.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the 'is clockwise of' condition here, since you can't compare angles using 'greater than' or 'less than' because they don't take in to account the fact angles over 360 wrap around back to 0.  Negate 'Is clockwise of' to mean 'Is anticlockwise of'.

For example:

[Negate] Is clockwise of 135 degrees: set angle to 135 degrees

Is clockwise of 45 degrees: set angle to 45 degrees